# count of of records containing string in SQL

Tags: sql, string, count

I have two strings in a column. I am looking to count.

`LIKE '%Alpha%' and LIKE '%Beta'%`

I am looking to just get a count of the number of times they appear in a table.  I thought this would be easy using `CASE`, but it doesn't seem to be fucntioning.

Comment: For column value 'AlphaBeta' is the count = 1 or = 2 or Alpha = 1 and Beta = 1?

Answer (score 2):

You can do aggregation :

```
select count(*)
from table t
where col like '%Alpha%' and col like '%Beta%';
```

If you want to separate count then you can do conditional aggergation instead :

```
select sum(case when col like '%Alpha%' then 1 else 0 end) as AlphaCnt,
       sum(case when col like '%Beta%' then 1 else 0 end) as BetaCnt
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count them separate from each other:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN col LIKE'%Alpha%' THEN 1 END) AS Alpha
,      COUNT(CASE WHEN col LIKE'%Beta%' THEN 1 END) AS Beta
FROM   table t
WHERE col LIKE '%Alpha%' 
   OR col LIKE '%Beta%';
```